# How to refresh a node.js application

Tags: node.js

I have made changes to the `javascript` and `html` used by a `node.js` app.  Afterwards the following were done:

- force reload the client/browser (repeatedly and before / after each step below)
- stop (`kill`)  the `node.js` app
- run `npm install .` from root dir of the app
- restart :  `node app.js`

However the old js/html files are being served.

The only way I could proceed was to do a full copy of the entire app into a new directory and rename the existing one *while the node.js app were shut down*.

Why can't i simply update the html and js files and force reload the client?  And even more so: how is that even killing the `app.js` process were insufficient?

Comment: It sounds like you're either not updating the files appropriately, not restarting the server appropriately or your browser has something cached.  There's no other place that things can get stuck on the old version.  I have no idea what `npm install` has to do with things here.  Won't that overwrite the changes you just made?

Comment: The first three of the possibilities you mention would seem to be  crossed off by the note that by copying the entire directory contents to a new directory it works.   afa `npm install .` i tried that only because the other steps were not sufficient. I did not think that should be required.